# React-Native: Requiring unknown module "react/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret"

Tags: react-native

I am trying to compile the master branch of the react-native repo to submit a PR. I am following the docs https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-building-from-source.html

But doing exactly what do docs says, I get the following error on android:

`Requiring unknown module "react/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret`

Also running on ios gives similar kind of error:

`Unable to resolve module react/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret from /Users/aakash/Projects/TestingPR/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Utilities/deprecatedPropType.js: Unable to find this module in its module map or any of the node_modules directories under /Users/node_modules/react/lib/ReactPropTypesSecret`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This issue occurs when an ReactNative-App based on RN 0.28 or older is upgraded to RN 0.30 or newer without to update also the "react"-package to at least 15.3.0.

Have you tried this?

If this will not solve your issue, you should provide your package.json.

Comment: Thank you, Upgrading react from 15.2.1 to 15.3.0 solved the issue.